# NoSuchHostedZone Error deploying AWS SAM with custom domain

Tags: aws-sam

Below is my HttpApi SAM resource template.

```
MyAuthApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Name: MyAuthApi
      Domain:
        DomainName: "auth.mysite.com"
        CertificateArn: !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:MY_ACM_ARN:1}}"
        EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:MY_HOSTED_ZONE:1}}}"
```

when I deploy with this template, the error below occurs.

```
No hosted zone found with ID:
Z~~actual HOSTED ZONE ID~~} (Service:
AmazonRoute53; Status Code: 404;
Error Code: NoSuchHostedZone;
```

during deployment, it got exact hosted zone ID from Parameter Store definitely, but print there's no such thing. though it actually exists.

but I found that deployment is successfully done if I type actual zone ID directly to the template, instead of making it refer the Parameter Store. ( like Z~~actual ID~~ instead of !Sub "~~" for HostedZoneId property. it works. )

But I don't want it to be hard-coded. so I wonder why it works like this.
Do you have got any idea why it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove an extra `}` at the end of the last line.

If that does not help, I think you need to provide a full path to SSM Parameters (and I do not believe you need a `!Sub`):

```
MyAuthApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Name: MyAuthApi
      Domain:
        DomainName: "auth.mysite.com"
        CertificateArn: "{{resolve:ssm:/MY_ACM_ARN:1}}"
        EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: "{{resolve:ssm:/MY_HOSTED_ZONE:1}}"
```